# UK DATV visa for round trip

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, applications, datv

I'm travelling from India to the Bahamas via London. I'm applying for UK DATV visa but it asks for `Date you plan to arrive in the UK` and `Date you plan to leave the UK`. I have layover in London in both sides of round trip.

Do I need to apply for two DATV visas? If not, what dates do I enter in the form?

Comment: Those questions are a bit odd. Is this an online application or a paper application?

Comment: @MichaelHampton its an online form. I've found the solution though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that you have to enter your first entry and exit dates in that form. Continue filling out the form and a few sections later it will ask you if you'll be transiting again as part of round trip. You have to enter your return details at this point.